# screenshot after onCreate

Tags: android, view, screenshot, oncreate

I am trying to capture the screenshot just after the activity showing , now I have one solution , that is like this

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ScreenManager.captureScreen();
            }
        }, 1500);
```

put the code in onCreate of activity , but I found sometimes the activity starts very slow , it is more than 1500 mm , then the bitmap captured will be empty , I want to find similar function or callback like onShown() or onDraw() , but failed to find it . Is there any callback which is called just when all views in the activity are shown , then I can put capture screen code here , I need this , thanks very much  .

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running ScreenManager.captureScreen() from onStart or onResume - they are called after onCreate. onResume will be called if the app goes into the background and back again though so you would need to create a boolean to check against.

Activity lifecycle diagram here may help: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I have tried onStart and onResume , both can't work , because at that time , view->getWidth()==0 , so it can't work , thanks man .

Comment: How about running an AsyncTask that checks if (view.getWidth()!=0) and then takes the screenshot?

Comment: I found another problem , the width >0 , but still some view components are not loaded on the screen , so the result is an empty transparent bitmap . how can I detect all the components of the view are loaded and put on the screen ?

Comment: Can you check each component does not equal null? Otherwise I'm afraid I'm out of ideas :-)

Comment: sorry , that's my hard point ,I can't check when all the components are loaded , actually I am trying to make my own home launcher of android ,I want to make the screenshot of all the screens in the workspace when launcher started . do you have any ideas about where I should put the screenshot code at launcher source code ? thanks very much , tony .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Following Code for taking Snapshot,

```
ImageView v1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mImage);
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: sorry , I guess you misunderstand my question , I know how to make the screenshot , the problem here is I can't make it just when the activity is shown . but thanks any way .